# Which are the Java JAXP XPath implementations available?

Tags: java, xml, implementation, jaxp, xpath

Which are the Java JAXP XPath implementations available? The default implementation, Xalan (shipped with the JVM), is very slow to evaluate XPath expressions, so, I'm looking for a faster implementation.

Comment: I've used Saxon's xpath with JAXP bindings. I haven't tried to compare performance. You need to set system property "javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:"+OBJECT_MODEL to "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl" before calling XPathFactory.neweInstance.
 Note that the default object model is different. If you want to keep the code that is processing the returned values the same and portable, you need to use the DOM_OBJECT_MODEL AND you need to explicitly pass a DOM node to XPath.evaluate. If you try to eval an InputSource, it will not return DOM results even when that is the requested object model.

Comment: You might also consider whether you can switch to Joost & stxpath, 
which is a streaming model: http://joost.sourceforge.net/
( I haven't tried this myself yet, but it's the next thing I'm going to look at. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried Saxon as Steven D. Majewski has recommended and it worked very well. The performance is far superior to Xalan (the default implementation shipped with the JVM). Also, by doing some research I've found that the GNU JAXP project has a implementation for the JAXP XPath API, although I’ve not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [VTD](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/34045)

Comment: It seems an interesting project but it is not an implementation for the JAXP XPath API.